# Is there a Google AppEngine compatible FW for building django REST API's (like piston etc.)?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, rest

I'm trying to build a REST API on top of django running on Google AppEngine.
Is there a FW with similar offering to piston (or a piston fork?) that can run on AppEngine models rather than on django's models?

Answer (score 2):

There is a project called [appengine-rest-server](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-rest-server/) that claims to do what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://code.google.com/p/django-rest-interface/

Comment: I'm looking for something that supports Google AppEngine models as opposed to django models

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying [wapi](http://abra.rm-fr.net/~fiam/code/wapi-0.2.1.zip), and it seems customizable enough to run on app-engine.

For instance the Serialization looks really easy to [specialize](http://fi.am/entry/building-a-website-api-with-django-part-5-serializ/) to non-django models. This example is part of the tutorial available [here](http://fi.am/entry/building-a-website-api-with-django-part-1-api-func/).